# Filter with callback misses some condition

Tags: php, closures

I have the following code to filter an array in PHP;  it works fine.  But after adding more filtering conditions, it stopped working.

Working code

```
$s_item = array_values(array_filter($itmlist, function ($itmlist) {
    return ($itmlist['itmslsprc'] > 0);
    }
));
```

Code that doesn't work after adding more conditions

```
$s_item = array_values(array_filter($itmlist, function ($itmlist) {
    return ($itmlist['itmslsprc'] > 0 && $today >= $itmlist['itmslsfr']  &&  $today <= $itmlist['itmslsto']);
    }
));
```

Both `$today` and the other dates have been initialised in format `2021-01-12 00:00:00`.

Can anyone tell what might have gone wrong?
Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: where is `$today` defined

Comment: if you want to use $today in a nested function you have to pass it! Probably your $today variable is undefined

Comment: What's the problem with different formats? "Doesn't work" sounds pretty broad, so what have you tried to debug it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your today is outside the function you can use it inside the function like this :

```
$s_item = array_values(array_filter($itmlist, function ($itmlist) use($today) {
    return ($itmlist['itmslsprc'] > 0 && $today >= $itmlist['itmslsfr']  &&  $today <= $itmlist['itmslsto']);
    }
));
```

Answer (score 0):

if your today is outside the function you can use "use"

Comment: Please avoid duplicating existing answers, unless you want to add something that hasn't been covered in other answers

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can just *import* the variable in the the callback's scope, relying on [`use` statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-180).

[PHP Closures](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) don't bind automatically to the outer scope (like it happens in languages like Javascript).

But if you stick to a more functional programming paradigm (and work with **PHP >=7.4**), you can avoid the manual import and rely on [PHP Arrow Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php).

```
$today = // your value here

$s_item = array_values(array_filter($itmlist, fn($itmlist) =>
    $itmlist['itmslsprc'] > 0 &&
    $today >= $itmlist['itmslsfr'] &&
    $today <= $itmlist['itmslsto']
));
```

`fn() => returnExpression` will have access to `$today`.

### Note

This is a *copy-by-value*, as reported in the manual:

> When a variable used in the expression is defined in the parent scope it will be implicitly captured by-value.

In case you want to modify the outer variable, and want no additional closure parameters, then `use` statement is your best option.